# How to develop web desktop using ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs4, webtop

I have learned basics of ExtJS and developed some web apps using ExtJS. Now I have to develop web desktop using ExtJS (like desktop app which is present in examples folder) but I am not able to find any documentation or tutorial or book about how to develop it.

Does anyone knows how to develop **web desktop application using ExtJS 4?** Where can I get any tutorial/ book/ video about developing web desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a book or tutorial dedicated to exactly what you're looking for, but you can put together enough resources across the internet to do the trick.

A Google search of "extjs 4 cookbook" turned up a book called "Ext JS 4 Web Application Development Cookbook" that seems to have plenty of information. However, it seems very new and I personally haven't read it, so I can't vouch for it. But it's there.

Other than that, Sencha's own documentation site will have most of what you need. The series of articles on App Architecture may be of some use if you're planning to take the MVC approach, as will the articles on components and layouts.

That will cover the basics, but there's no real definitive guide to making a web desktop app that I'm aware of. It all depends on what your requirements are, how much time you have available, etc. If you're looking for help with a specific component (like creating a Windows-style file browser system) then you'll probably have better luck asking more narrow questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Even I have come up with the conclusion that there's no book or tutorial available for ExtJS webtop. I know basics of ExtJS and I can develop windows, menus, charts, etc. So I just wanted to move one step ahead and create some nice webtop like application, hence the question.

Comment: one more silly question. Any idea why Sencha has not provided any documentation about this webtop? Is this webtop thing still 'work in progress' or they dont prefer this kind of application? I was totally impressed with webtop application concept but now I have to look at the example that came with SDK...

Again, thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I have a feeling it was created for the purpose of showing off Ext JS to potential customers, not necessarily as a reference for developers. Sencha's documentation tends use "here's the code, you figure it out" examples rather than "here's step 1, step 2, and why it works" tutorials. Which is unfortunate, because you can do some amazing things once you figure out how the internals work. Good luck with your project! PS: If you haven't noticed, the webtop example was updated with the release of Ext JS 4.1. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/desktop/desktop.html

Comment: ya, even I a also think that Sencha has given that webtop example just to show off, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use default Web Desktop Sample provided by Sencha and modify it a little bit.
I am also interested in, I did what I advice you, so you can look what I have received now:
http://www.bdovhan.orgfree.com/

Hmmm, these free hosting providers use lot of ads if your site becomes clickable.
I created another mirror, there should be no ads: http://www.julfysoft.16mb.com/index.html
but it can take a while to load it...

Answer (score 1):

We inspired from the desktop sample and we build a full functional web app using Extj 6.7 along with Unigui Framework (Delphi), and the result is awsome:

[image]

Just implementing the idea step by step.